# Чтение кафка-топика двумя репликами

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Какие настройки нужно применить для Consumer-а в java приложении, когда два экземпляра приложения (то есть два листенера) читают одновременно один топик с одной партицией?
Необходимо задать, чтобы одно сообщение читалось/обрабатывалось только одним из двух экземпляров

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/354486/

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтоб несколько потребителей читали сообщения скоординировано и каждое сообщение попадало только одному потребителю нужно им назначить одинаковую группу.

Вот соответствующая часть примера из [документации](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/clients/docs/java.html#client-examples-java):

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;


final Properties props = ...

...
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "demo-consumer-1");

final Consumer<String, DataRecord> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, DataRecord>(props);
```

Comment: Если вы не увеличите кол-во партиций, то не важно сколько экземпляров будет с одной Consumer group. Читать будет только один, остальные простаивать.

Comment: Это правда, но у автора вопроса проблема, кажется, не в этом. Если у него читатели не в одной группе, то не важно, что у вас только одна партиция, читать и обрабатывать они будут параллельно.